# Order weird data linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dynamic object list in following format

```
period       key      value
"2013-3"     mykey1   5
"2013-4"     mykey1   6
.
.
.
"2013-10"    mykey1   15
"2013-11"    mykey1   25
"2013-12"    mykey1   6
```

what I want is to get the values where key=="mykey1" ordered by period.

I tried as below..

```
data.Where(w => w.key  == "mykey1").OrderBy(i => i.period).Select(s => s.value).ToArray();
```

What happens is as period is string, you get data from 2013-10 to 2013-12 before 2013-3.

Comment: I would suggest to store your period as `DateTime` if possible. so you don't have overhead of parsing in each query.

Comment: the data is coming from 3rd party, so no control there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
data.Where(w => w.key  == "mykey1").OrderBy(i => DateTime.ParseExact(i.period, "yyyy-M",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Select(s => s.value).ToArray();
```

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I found the change of yyyy-MM to yyyy-M and tried but still same error..

Comment: Is `period` able null or empty ?

Comment: needed (string)i.period

Comment: Yes. period type is `dynamic` and you must convert to `string` http://rextester.com/BVUXZZ10097

Answer (score 1):

This is because it is sorting `string` values not `Date` values.

You may try to parse the values to dates in the `OrderBy` clause.

Something like:

```
data.Where(w => w.key  == "mykey1")
    .OrderBy(i => DateTime.Parse(i.period)).Select(s => s.value).ToArray();
```

Comment: it throws an error The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments maybe because period in my case does not have a day value.. The parse method also takes a second param FormatProvider and third DateTimeStyles.. Will adding any help??

Comment: Yes @Arnab i was just explaining the sample, the TryParse method or pre-check will do the trick for you. sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can pad with zeroes. Something like this:

```
data.Where(w => w.key  == "mykey1").OrderBy(i => i.period.PadLeft(i.period.Max(x => x), '0'))
    .Select(s => s.value).ToArray();
```

The pad's result will be:

```
"02013-3",
"02013-4",
"2013-10",
"2013-11",
"2013-12"
```

And so it will orders this list as expected.